# Options -Indexes From root .htaccess for entire website?

Tags: php, apache

Is there a way to prevent directory listing from the root .htaccess?

I actually use this ->

```
Options -Indexes 

Options All -Indexes
```

Both doesn`t work for me in root

Only works if I crete an .htaccess for each folder my script create dynamic folders and is not good way create one for each folder creation I guess.

Thanks

David

Answer (score 0):

Create an .htaccess-file in your root directory. Then place this piece of code inside of it:

```
Options -Indexes 
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php
```

What this does is prevent the listing of all directories AND redirects to your index.php-file everytime if someone tries to visit one of your (sub-)folders directly. If it still doesn't work then there might be a problem with the settings of your host.